# Why are my API Pie parameters not showing up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apipie

I created the documentation for my methods, and the top-level method description shows up along with its verb, but when I click on any of these links it tells me "Oops!! Method `create.en` not found for resource `questions`."

Here is an example of my code:

```
  api :DELETE, '/questions/:id', 'Deletes question. Note that the delete cascades and also removes any child questions.'
  param :id, :number
  def destroy
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    @question.destroy_cascade
    head :ok
  end
```

And here's what the page looks like – all of these links take me to an error page

[image]

Weirdly, if I look at the json version it seems to be fine (i.e. it includes all the information).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up needing to add these lines to the initializer:

```
  config.default_locale          = 'en'
  config.languages               = ['en']
```